# Можно ли это назвать хеш-таблицей. Если нет то почему ?

Tags: data-structures, структуры-данных, алгоритм, хеширование, c++

Почитал кормена и написал хеш-таблицу на основе сцепления элементов. Можно ли это назвать хеш-таблицей и если нет то почему, какие ошибки есть логические ?

node.hpp

```
#ifndef NODE_HPP
#define NODE_HPP

template <class T>
class list;

template <class T>
class node
{
    private:
        friend class list<T>;

    private:
        node* m_next;
        node* m_prev;
        T m_data;

    public:
        node() :  m_next(0)
                , m_prev(0)
                , m_data(0) {}

        explicit node(T d) :  m_next(0)
                            , m_prev(0)
                            , m_data(d) {}
        T get_data()
        {
            return m_data;
        }
};

#endif // NODE_HPP
```

list.hpp

```
#ifndef LIST_HPP
#define LIST_HPP

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

#include "node.hpp"

template <class T>
class list
{
    private:
        node<T>* m_head;
        node<T>* m_tail;
        unsigned m_size;

    public:
        list() :   m_size(0) 
                 , m_head(0)
                 , m_tail(0){}

        node<T>* get_new_node(T d) const;
        node<T>* find(T data) const;
        void insert_at_front(T data);
        void insert_at_back(T data);
        void delete_at_front();
        void delete_at_back();
        bool is_empty() const;
        void print() const;
        node<T>* get_begin() const
        {
            return m_head;
        }
        node<T>* get_end() const
        {
            return m_tail;
        }
        unsigned get_size() const
        {
            return m_size;
        }
};

template <class T>
node<T>* list<T>::get_new_node(T data) const 
{
    node<T>* n = new node<T>(data);
    assert(n != 0);
    return n;
}

template <class T>
bool list<T>::is_empty() const
{
    if(m_head == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template <class T>
void list<T>::print() const 
{
    if(is_empty())
    {
        return;
    }
    node<T>* t = m_head;
    while(t != 0)
    {
        std::cout << t->m_data << " ";
        t = t->m_next;
    }
}

template <class T>
node<T>* list<T>::find(T data) const
{
    if(is_empty())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    node<T>* t = m_head;
    while(t != 0 && t->m_data != data)
    {
        t = t->m_next;
    }
    return t;
}

template <class T>
void list<T>::insert_at_front(T data)
{
    node<T>* n = get_new_node(data);
    if(m_head == 0)
    {
        m_head = m_tail = n;
        n->m_next = n->m_prev = 0;
        ++m_size;
    }
    else
    {
        n->m_next = m_head;
        if(m_head != 0)
        {
            m_head->m_prev = n;
        }
        m_head = n;
        n->m_prev = 0;
        ++m_size;
    }
}

template <class T>
void list<T>::insert_at_back(T data)
{
    node<T>* n = get_new_node(data);
    if(m_tail == 0)
    {
        m_head = m_tail = n;
        n->m_next = n->m_prev = 0;
        ++m_size;
    }
    else
    {
        m_tail->m_next = n;
        n->m_prev = m_tail;
        m_tail = n;
        ++m_size;
    }

}

template <class T>
void list<T>::delete_at_front()
{
    if(is_empty())
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        node<T>* t = m_head->m_next;
        t->m_prev = 0;
        delete m_head;
        m_head = t;
        --m_size;
    }
}

template <class T>
void list<T>::delete_at_back()
{
    if(is_empty())
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        node<T>* t = m_tail->m_prev;
        t->m_next = 0;
        delete m_tail;
        m_tail = t;
        --m_size;
    }
}

#endif // LIST_HPP
```

hash_table.hpp

```
#ifndef HASH_TABLE_HPP
#define HASH_TABLE_HPP

#include "list.hpp"

template <class T>
class hash_table
{
    private:
        list<T>** m_table;
        unsigned m_size;

    private:
        int get_hash(int key);

    public:
        explicit hash_table(unsigned);
        T find(const T&, const T&); 
        void insert(const T&, unsigned);
        void remove(const T&);
};

template <class T>
hash_table<T>::hash_table(unsigned size)
{
    m_size = size;
    m_table = new list<T>*[m_size];
    for(int i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
    {
        m_table[i] = new list<T>();
    }
}

template <class T>
int hash_table<T>::get_hash(int key)
{
    return (key % m_size);
}

template <class T>
T hash_table<T>::find(const T& d, const T& i)
{
    int h = get_hash(i);
    node<T>* n = m_table[h]->find(d);
    assert(n != 0);
    return n->get_data();
}

template <class T>
void hash_table<T>::insert(const T& d, unsigned key)
{
    unsigned h = get_hash(key);
    m_table[h]->insert_at_front(d);
}

#endif // HASH_TABLE_HPP
```

Поправил код find(...)

```
template <class T>
T hash_table<T>::find(const T& i)
{
    int h = get_hash(i);
    if(m_table[h]->get_begin() != 0)
    {
        return m_table[h]->get_begin()->get_data();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

но так получается что функция всегда возвращает только голову списка а если есть коллизия то этот случай не учитывается ... ?

Comment: А почему `list` наследует `node` (да ещё и публично)? Разве он _является_ разновидностью `node`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Есть несколько замечаний по реализации:

> - Непонятна сигнатура `find(T, T)`. Почему не `find(Key)`?
> - Непонятно ваше разделение `<Key, Value>` для элементов хэш-таблицы. То есть, сигнатуры методов должны выглядеть как `insert(Key, Value) / find(Key) / remove(Key)`, либо как `insert(Value) / find(Value) / remove(Value)` для случая, когда в хэш-таблице хранятся не пары ключ-значение, а сами значения. **Других вариантов нет.**
> - Не предложена имплементация `remove(T)`. Вместо траты времени на реализацию своего `std::list<T>,` лучше бы уж написали метод удаления элементов из хэш-таблицы.
> - Крайне странное решение, в котором вызов функции `find()` `coredump'ится` в случае отсутствующего в хэш-таблице значения.
> - Вообще, предложенный код, за исключением последних пятнадцати строчек, не имеет к хэш-таблицам никакого отношения, а просто предлагает какой-то неочевидный способ реализации аналога `std::list`. Решение с наследованием `node<T>` ← `list<T>,` кстати, кажется очень странным.

- А так, ну да, обычная хэш-таблица с `chaining'ом` для резолвинга коллизий.

Comment: 1.find(T, Т) сигнатура этой функции в книге такова Chained-Hash- Search(T, k) где T массив из спсиков а k ключ, вот и я так поступил а если бы не было второго параметра то сложность алгоритма выросла бы из О(1+а) в О(n^2) потому что так придется посмотреть все списки в масиве а это уже квадратичная сложность и это уже не хеш-таблица.
Правильно заметили убрал наследование.

Comment: @Վարդան Գրիգորյան

- У Кормена алгоритм `Chained-Hash-Search(T, k)` принимает два параметра — хэш-таблицу `T`, представленную в виде массива списков и ключ `k`. Ваш метод `hash_table<T>::find` принимает **два значения,** причем хэш-функция вызывается для второго аргумента, а в списке коллизий для значения хэш-функции почему-то ищется первый.

- То есть, фактически, ваш метод имеет сигнатуру `find(T, v, v),` в который первый параметр подставляется неявно и всегда равен `m_table`.

- Напишите реальный пример использования вашего `hash_table<T>::find`, и вы поймете, что я имею ввиду.

Comment: - `find(Key)` — это то же самое, что `find(T, Key)`, когда `T` является членом класса, поэтому на алгоритмическую сложность это влияния не оказывает, и она все еще остается равной `O(1 + 1 / A)` в случае идеального равномерного хэширования.

- Правильный список, в котором нужно искать ключ, получается за `O(1)` как `T[h(Key)],` поэтому ваше утверждение про деградацию сложности до `O(N^2)` мне кажется сомнительным.

Comment: Поправил код find(...)

template <class T>
T hash_table<T>::find(const T& i)
{
    int h = get_hash(i);
    if(m_table[h]->get_begin() != 0)
    {
        return m_table[h]->get_begin()->get_data();
    }
    return 0;
}
но так получается что функция всегда возвращает только голову списка а если есть коллизия то этот случай не учитывается ... ?

Comment: @Вардан: да, вам ещё надо в списке найти нужный элемент линейным поиском:

    auto n = m_table[h]->find(h);
    if (n)
        return n->get_data();

Comment: @VladD Только не `find(h),` а `find(i)`.

Comment: И правда, `find(i)`, спасибо!

Comment: Нельзя ли писать "разрешение" вместо "резолвинг"?
P.S.: Да, по существу вопроса у меня возражений нет :)

Comment: @Flammable Мицгол, залогиньтесь :)

Answer (score 4):

Похоже, что да, это может быть хэш таблицей. Для начала читаем определение с [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0):

```
Хеш-табли́ца — это структура данных, реализующая интерфейс ассоциативного массива, а именно, она позволяет хранить пары (ключ, значение) и выполнять три операции: операцию добавления новой пары, операцию поиска и операцию удаления пары по ключу.
```

Все эти три операции я  вижу. Правда было бы  не плохо перегрузить `operator []` (что бы реализовать интерфейс "массива").

Меня  только смущает порядок параметров в функции вставки. Я думаю, ключ должен идти первым.

Обязательно напишите тестовые примеры и проверьте, что бы Ваша таблица работала как нужно.

Comment: Рискну не согласиться с википедией. Имхо особенность хэш-талицы в том, что она определяет местонахождение значения на основе хэша ключа. Теоретически можно просто создать массив пар <ключ, значение>, делать простой линейный поиск и в соответствии с вики это тоже будет хэш-таблица.

Comment: Ну не буду я всю википедию копировать сюда. Чуточку ниже есть примечание:

> Важное свойство хеш-таблиц состоит в том, что, при некоторых разумных допущениях, все три операции (поиск, вставка, удаление элементов) в среднем выполняются за время O(1). 

В автора вопроса она вполне может быть такой, все зависит от кол-ва элементов, которые он туда будет пытаться засунуть (у него хеш функция простая - модуль, но для простеньких хеш таблиц она может быть в самый раз).

Comment: спасибо за аргументированный ответ, обязательно напишу operator[] и поправлю порядок параметров функции вставки и еще деструктор надо в class -е hash_table